# Windows phone emulators

Tags: windows-phone-8, hyper-v, windows-phone-8-emulator

I recently installed windows phone SDK to create apps for my phone. First I installed it on my W8.1 laptop (64 bit) and tried to execute an app like this:

I created the project, succesfully build it and deployed the XAP file with the "application deployment" program. I selected the emulator 7.1 (v8 isn't shown up) as target and when I launched it i got the folowing error:

- Unable to deploy this app to the device because it targets a version of windows phone that is higher than what the device supports.

I didn't really find an answer on google, so I tried to deploy it straight from the MS VS 2012 windows phone program with device:  and ARM, got the folowing error:

- A screen saying this isn't compatible.

I did some googeling and found out that I need hyper v enabled. I went to the bios, enabled it, but it doesn't show hyper v in my control panel program list. (my laptop does meet all the requirements for it...strange)

Some further googeling told em I had to install Visual studio 2013, I did that, and now my Visual studio windows phone program can't start and pops up the folowing error:

- cannot find one or more components, please reinstall the application.... great

I gave up on that computer and decided to switch to my other laptop (w8 64 bit) to give that one a shot, same proces, I installed the SDK, tryed to enable virtualizing in bios but it wasn't there, altho it showed up in my program list. But I can't select any emulator from the visual studio windows phone program (only "device" can be selected). I tried to deploy the XAP file with the application deployment program but same error as with the other computer (probably because V8 isn't in the list either)

The last thing I tried was opening the V8 emulator but it coulnd launch because I needed a second addess translation....

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your Windows Phone project is targeting the WP8 SDK, while your physical phone is a WP7. Is that correct?

If you have a WP7 phone, you'll need a phone project targeting the WP7.1 SDK which you can download here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=27570.

As for your WP8 emulator troubles, it looks like your processor does not support SLAT. It is a requirement as listed here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff626524(v=vs.105).aspx. If that's indeed the case, as far as I know your only option is to use the WP7.1 emulator (that comes with the SDK) or use a computer with a newer processor.

Comment: I have an intel (r) core (tm) i7-4700MQ processor. And I just saw my project mate running succesfully the emulator with the same device, and he didn't do anything special. I'll give your solution a look when I'm home. Thanks!

Comment: I installed visual studio ultimate 2012, then installed the windows phone SDK 8, and now it seems like I can run the emulator (only 7.1), the emulator 8 gives me an error saying I have to enable hyper-v.